# how to pop up a modal upon putting the cursor in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a small textarea, and as the user puts the cursor inside it, I want a modal to popup as a larger version of this textarea.
I prepared all code, but couldn't find the part of putting the cursor in the textarea to populate the modal.

Textarea :

```
 <textarea href ="#s-fb" class="form-control" name="sfb" id="sfb" rows="2" value="" placeholder="We would appreciate your feedback to improve the website"></textarea>
```

Modal :

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="s-fb">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
...
...
...
```

Comment: do you want to display big textarea in model? when click in texarea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this one.

```js
$('#sfb').click(function(){
  $('#s-fb').modal('show')
})
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use onmouseover event to trigger an event when the mouse is placed over the textarea. 
`onmouseover="showModal()"`

```
function showModal(){
   document.getElementById('s-fb').style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `onmouseover` function for your text input.  Something like this will work:

```
<input type="text" onmouseover="$('#exampleModal').modal('show')">


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```